# APEX 19.2 : Command line utility APEXExport throws error

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I am trying to export my application using the command line utility APEXExport. (APEX 19.2)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_APPLICATION'

ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored





    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:223)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:56)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:907)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1300)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3887)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4230)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)

    at oracle.apex.APEXExport.exec_and_write_files(APEXExport.java:222)

    at oracle.apex.APEXExport.ExportFile(APEXExport.java:523)

    at oracle.apex.APEXExport.ExportFiles(APEXExport.java:332)

    at oracle.apex.APEXExport.main(APEXExport.java:890)

Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 17, Sql = begin

:1  := apex_export.get_application (

         p_application_id          => :2 ,

         p_split                   => :3 ='Y',

         p_with_date               => :4 ='Y',

         p_with_ir_public_reports  => :5 ='Y',

         p_with_ir_private_reports => :6 ='Y',

         p_with_ir_notifications   => :7 ='Y',

         p_with_translations       => :8 ='Y',

         p_with_pkg_app_mapping    => :9 ='Y',

         p_with_original_ids       => :10 ='Y',

         p_with_no_subscriptions   => :11 ='Y',

         p_with_comments           => :12 ='Y',

         p_with_supporting_objects => :13 ,

         p_with_acl_assignments    => :14 ='Y',

         p_components              => apex_string.split(:15 ,'#') );

end;, OriginalSql = begin

? := apex_export.get_application (

         p_application_id          => ?,

         p_split                   => ?='Y',

         p_with_date               => ?='Y',

         p_with_ir_public_reports  => ?='Y',

         p_with_ir_private_reports => ?='Y',

         p_with_ir_notifications   => ?='Y',

         p_with_translations       => ?='Y',

         p_with_pkg_app_mapping    => ?='Y',

         p_with_original_ids       => ?='Y',

         p_with_no_subscriptions   => ?='Y',

         p_with_comments           => ?='Y',

         p_with_supporting_objects => ?,

         p_with_acl_assignments    => ?='Y',

         p_components              => apex_string.split(?,'#') );

end;, Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_APPLICATION'

ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored





    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)

    ... 18 more
```

I ran a fairly staright forward command from cmd

```
cd <Navigated to utilites folder in apex installation>

%JAVA_HOME%\java oracle.apex.APEXExport -db "myhost:myport:servicename" -user my_user -password my_password -applicationid 120
```

However, when i use APEX 18.2 installation, application is exported without issues.

Let me know if i am doing it wrong? Or is it a bug in APEX 19.2 (not listed in know issues)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays I would recommend using SQLcl instead of the "old" APEXExport utility...
SQLcl has built in APEX export tools which work nicely and have all the features of the old utility plus some more. Just connect with SQLcl to your DB parsing schema and type "apex export" for a command help page.

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html

[apex export command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA6jA.jpg)